# Bluetooth Not Discovering Devices on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: bluetooth

I recently installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu, and I'm encountering issues with my Bluetooth. When attempting to scan for nearby devices, none are detected. However, during my previous Windows installation, all nearby devices were visible.

**I've already tried various basic troubleshooting commands, such as:**

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
sudo hciconfig hci0 up

rfkill unblock
```

**Here's some information about my Bluetooth hardware:**

```
lsusb | grep -i bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 3168 Bluetooth
```

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth

bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-11-28 12:10:11 EST; 4min 18s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 7368 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18993)
     Memory: 808.0K
        CPU: 75ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─7368 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Nov 28 12:10:11 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Nov 28 12:10:11 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Nov 28 12:10:12 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 28 12:10:12 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 28 12:10:12 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Nov 28 12:10:12 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Nov 28 12:10:12 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Nov 28 12:10:12 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Nov 28 12:10:12 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Nov 28 12:10:12 linux bluetoothd[7368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
```

While the service is running, there seems to be an issue with setting the mode, indicated by "Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)."

If additional information is needed, please let me know, and I'll gladly provide it. I appreciate any assistance you can offer. Thank you!

Comment: same issue here... can anyone point us to a troubleshooting guide? Mine is realtek: 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:b85b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio